# Is there a cross-platform way to run a command daily at a certain time?

Tags: powershell

Let's say I'd like to run a command every weekday at 10:15 AM.

On Linux I can use `cron`. On Windows I can use `Task Scheduler`.

I'd like a way to do this entirely in PowerShell.

Here's one approach:

```
$dates = @(foreach ($i in 1..100)
{
    (Get-Date (Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd') -Hour 10 -Minute 5).AddDays($i)
}) | Where-Object { $_.DayOfWeek -notin 'Saturday', 'Sunday' }

while ($true)
{
    if ((Get-Date) -ge $dates[0])
    {
        $dates = $dates | Select-Object -Skip 1

        echo 'running command' 
        
        # Run command here
    }

    echo ("Not yet {0}" -f $dates[0])
    
    Start-Sleep -Seconds (60*5)
}
```

## Question

Is there already an accepted way to do this directly in PowerShell?

If not, is there a better approach than the above?

Comment: Do you need it to survive system restarts? E.g. reboots after Windows Updates? What happens if the script fails e.g. out of memory exceptions? Or you forget about it and it runs all 100 iterations and exits? These are all handled by the native cron / scheduled task systems -  the overhead of re-implementing all the resilience functionality might make it less work overall to just use the two different native solutions…

Comment: Hi @mclayton! The script does not need to automatically continue after system restarts.

Comment: In that case, to the best of my knowledge there’s no “one” idiomatic way in PowerShell to do what you’re doing, and it depends on your specific needs as to how you measure what it “better”. If what you’ve already written works for you then it’s probably fine to stick with…